# Geoserver behind Nginx : strange behavior with HTTPS

Tags: nginx, geoserver

I need your help for a strange problem :)

I have Geoserver on my server :

- it is a standalone daemon (not a WAR deployed in Tomcat)
- it is listening on 127.0.0.1:8280
- I have a PROXY_BASE_URL configured like this: https://geoserver.example.com/geoserver
- the option "Use headers for Proxy URL" is checked at this moment but I tried by unchecking it

I have a Nginx in front of Geoserver to manage the SSL offloading.
The vhost is :

```
upstream backend-geoserver {
    server 127.0.0.1:8280    weight=10    max_fails=3    fail_timeout=15s;
}

server {
    server_name geoserver.example.com;

    listen 443 ssl;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access-geoserver.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error-geoserver.log;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ /geoserver;
    }

    location /geoserver {
        proxy_set_header    Host                  $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port      $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto     $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server    $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP             $remote_addr;

        proxy_pass http://backend-geoserver/geoserver;
    }
}
```

When I reach my server on https://geoserver.example.com it works: I see the home page of Geoserver

Important detail : the port 80 is closed and I can't open it myself: the Nginx server can only answer on 443

When I try to login, I have a connection timeout after X seconds and, at this moment, the URL in my browser (Firefox) is HTTP://geoserver.example.com/geoserver/ <--- please note the protocol is HTTP not HTTPS

If I replace http:// with https:// and press Enter: I reach the page

If I click on a link in Geoserver, same behavior: it switches on http:// and I have to force the URL manually.

Is anyone has an idea please ?!

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should have to get that port 80 open and configure nginx to redirect unsecure traffic over to https://

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you @akrizs : what you said is exactly what I tought.

The cloud provider opened me the port 80 and now it works :)


I confess at this moment I still don't know why this port 80 is required when all set configured to use https


I had a progression in my analysis at a moment. If I reconfigure my proxy_pass to proxy_pass http://backend-geoserver I obtained an index page with all applications deployed (geoserver + I don't remember what exactly). When I clicked on the application "geoserver" it worked. But I was not able to redirect directly to "/geoserver" with this solution :)