# Cannot log in Geoserver behind nginx in HTTPS

Tags: nginx, https, geoserver

Based in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72711863/geoserver-behind-nginx-strange-behavior-with-https), I have set up a standalone Geoserver (which uses Jetty) behind  nginx on a Ubuntu 22.04.3 server. My configuration file for nginx is:

```
upstream backend-geoserver {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=15s;
}

server {
        server_name myserver.com;
        access_log /var/logs/nginx-access.log;
        error_log /var/logs/nginx-error.log;

        location /static/ {
                expires -1;
                alias /home/user/static/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }

        location /geoserver {
                proxy_set_header    Host                  $host;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host      $host;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port      $server_port;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto     $scheme;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server    $host;
                proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP             $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://backend-geoserver/geoserver;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = myserver.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name myserver.com;
    return 404;
}
```

The base url `https://myserver.com` is redirected to a gunicorn socket with a django application which works fine.

When I connect to `https://myserver.com/geoserver`, I have the Geoserver main page, but I cannot log in as an admin. When I enter the default credentials and click on the log in button, I have the Chrome message: "The information you’re about to submit is not secure.
Because this form is being submitted using a connection that’s not secure, your information will be visible to others."

Checking the requests console, I see that the credentials are sent in HTTP, which tells me I probably need to set up Geoserver to use HTTPS only (following this [link](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html)), but I cannot change the parameters from the browser interface as I cannot log in.

There must be a way to configure Geoserver via terminal but I didn't find how ?